# word 2003 vba bug? DocumentBeforePrint execute twice?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is this a Word 2003 VBA bug? DocumentBeforePrint executes multiple times?

I reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211873(v=office.11).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211915(v=office.11).aspx

[DocumentBeforeClose syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693798/documentbeforeclose-syntax)

I make a test.dot with macro DocumentBeforePrint.

```
'ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211915(v=office.11).aspx
Dim X As New EventClassModule

Sub Register_Event_Handler()
Set X.appWord = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub Document_New()
   Call Register_Event_Handler
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
   Call Register_Event_Handler
End Sub


'ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211873(v=office.11).aspx

Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application

Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforePrint _
    (ByVal Doc As Document, _
    Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox "WORKING!"
End Sub
```

When  I press Ctrl+P, the macro executes.

There is a bug. When I double click test.dot to generate two word files (a.doc/b.doc).

Press Ctrl+P,the DocumentBeforePrint will execute *twice*.

If I generate 3 word files, Press Ctrl+P, the Macro will execute three times.

What's wrong? I just want to execude once.

Comment: You don't provide enough accurate information: I assume the code you do give us is not all in the same module? Please separate it and indicate in what modules the various procedures are located.

Comment: I upload the test file to google drive .https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aCwSQY4TCWWsU73fLVuNdloy22H3XW-m

Comment: I'm not going to download your document that contains macros. Please use the [edit] link to amend your original question with the information about in which modules the various procedures are stored - they certainly are not all in one module?

Comment: See my edited answer, and you'll understand why I asked my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have put all the code except the printing code in the `ThisDocument` code module. This is incorrect. Because you put ^Dim X as NewEventClassModule`in`ThisDocument`, which is, itself, a class module representing *each document*, multiple instances were being created. Declaring it in a "plain module" doesn't cause this problem.

You need three modules:

"Plain" module:

```
Dim X As New EventClassModule

Sub Register_Event_Handler()
  Set X.appWord = Word.Application
End Sub
```

"ThisDocument" module:

```
Private Sub Document_New()
   Register_Event_Handler
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
   Register_Event_Handler
End Sub
```

"EventClassModule"

```
Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application

Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforePrint _
    (ByVal Doc As Document, _
    Cancel As Boolean)

    MsgBox "WORKING!"
End Sub
```